# Store javascript variable in data attribute and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/0zppxL95/

I'm trying to store a jQuery variable in a html data attribute
and then get that value when I click a button.

Is it possible to do this, or how would I store a javascript variable and then retrieve it.

This will be in a loop so I wanted to store it on the variable on this object connected to the button so I can say when this button is clicked get this variable.

```
        var test = 'Hello';

        $('button').click(function(){
            var output = $(this).parent().attr('data-text');
            alert(output);
        })
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign the value of `data-text` to the `var test` when you click the button?

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to be working.  What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set data using [`.data(key,value)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
$(this).parent().data('text',test);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0zppxL95/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it setting the `attr` value and then retrieving it as you are doing now:

```
var test = 'Hello';

$('button').click(function(){
    //set the variable
    $(this).parent().attr('data-text', test);

    //get the variable
    var output = $(this).parent().attr('data-text');
    alert(output);
})
```

[Living example](http://jsfiddle.net/0zppxL95/1/)

Answer (score 1):

For setting the data attribute you need to use:

```
$(this).parent().data('text',test);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9uzyy1/)**